# Single Quote in LINQ Results Causing Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following LINQ query:

```
            Dim find_id = From p In dbContext.Residents _
                      Where p.person_name = occupant _
                      Select p
```

I then pull the first returned ID like so:

```
            Dim building_id As String = find_building_id.FirstOrDefault.id
```

This works fine, except with the person has a ' in their last name, like M'arta. In this case I get a NullReferenceException. Any thoughts on how I can get around this issue?

Okay, the problem appears to be that when I am capturing the name initially from a GridView it is inserting into the value a #39 instead of ' and then LINQ is keeping things correct, so I end up with a non-match since it is attempting to match:

> M#38arta = M'arta

Comment: Are you sure that the name you're using to search for them is correctly specified?

Comment: Positive. But it has a ' in it.

Comment: That really shouldn't cause any problems for EF. Have you had a look at the SQL being sent?

Comment: do `find_id.ToTraceString()` before iterating and show what you get

Comment: find_id.ToTraceString() doesn't work, I'm using EF LINQ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's an Unicode issue? I once had trouble with wrong settings of the 'Unicode' attribute of scalar string properties. Maybe your SQL connection string has defined a wrong charset? And are your sure it's a single quote and no kind of accent or a special char, looking similiar but with another code?

Just my spontanious ideas at night.